# I am trying to connect multiple functions and buttons together using js. and html. and I'm not sure what i'm missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I open the Html file in the browser, it shows that the two are connected properly but it wont output anything I type into the box.I just need it to output the function result depending on which button was pressed. Any help or advice is appreciated.

```js
function reverseStr(s) {
  var o = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i <= len; i++)
    o.push(s.charAt(len - i));
  return o.join('');
}
reverseStr("Hello");

var ch = "a";
    var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i ;

    isVowelR(ch, pattern);     

    function isVowelR(ch,pattern){
       if(pattern.test(ch)){
       return true;        
    }
      else{return false}
    }

    function countVowles(str1)
{
  var vowel_list = 'aeiouAEIOU';
  var vcount = 0;
  
  for(var x = 0; x < str1.length ; x++)
  {
    if (vowel_list.indexOf(str1[x]) !== -1)
    {
      vcount += 1;
    }
  
  }
  return vcount;
}
console.log(countVowles(""));

var pattern = /[0-9]/;
 function isDigit(regexp){
    if(pattern.test(regexp)){
        return true;
    }
    else{return false}
}



var main = function() {
  document.getElementByld("#inpt").value;
    //this keyword is set to the button that fired the event
    console.log(this.id);
    //dispatch on button id
    if (this.id == "btn1")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "You clicked Button1";
    else if (this.id == "btn2")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "You clicked Button2";
    else if (this.id == "btn3")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "You clicked Button3";
      else
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "You Clicked Button4";

};

//2. register the onclick handlers after the DOM is complete
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    //select the buttons
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

    //register the same handler for each button
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Buttons Demo </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>String Machine</h2>
<p>
Enter a String: 
</p>
<input id= "inpt"> </input>
<button id="btn1">Reverse</button>
<button id="btn2">Vowel or no Vowel</button>
<button id="btn3">Count Vowels</button>
<button id="btn4">Digit or no Digit</button>
<br>
<hr style="width:23%; margin-left:0;">
<div id="outDiv"></div>
<script src="stringMach.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the errors in the console? they help you understand where your code is wrong .. e.g. it's `getElementById` not `getElementByld` (upper case I d, not lower case L d)

Comment: just remove the document.getElementById and it should work

Comment: Also, its `document.getElementById("inpt")`, not `document.getElementById("#inpt")`. You dont add the `#` if you're using plain js.

Comment: The code shown doesn't call the string functions (except for a call to `reverseStr("Hello");` that doesn't do anything with the result). Your `main()` function would need to call whichever function related to the button that was clicked.

Comment: @Demonyowh When I removed document.getElemtByID it told me which button I pushed, but it did not run the function. I'm also pretty sure I didn't connect the two but have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine. Hope it'll helps

```js
function reverseStr(s) {
  var o = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = s.length; i <= len; i++)
    o.push(s.charAt(len - i));
  return o.join('');
}
reverseStr("Hello");

var ch = "a";
var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i ;

isVowelR(ch, pattern);     

function isVowelR(ch,pattern){
    if(pattern.test(ch)){
       return true;        
    }
    else{ return false }
}

    function countVowles(str1)
{
  var vowel_list = 'aeiouAEIOU';
  var vcount = 0;
  
  for(var x = 0; x < str1.length ; x++)
  {
    if (vowel_list.indexOf(str1[x]) !== -1)
    {
      vcount += 1;
    }
  
  }
  return vcount;
}

var pattern = /[0-9]/;
 function isDigit(regexp){
    if(pattern.test(regexp)){
        return true;
    }
    else{return false}
}



var main = function() {
    //this keyword is set to the button that fired the event
    var str = document.getElementById('inpt').value;
    var pattern =/a|e|i|o|u|y/i ;
    var pattern2 = /[0-9]/;
    
    console.log(this.id);
    //dispatch on button id
    if (this.id == "btn1")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = reverseStr(str);
    else if (this.id == "btn2")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = isVowelR(str, pattern);
    else if (this.id == "btn3")
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = countVowles(str);
      else
        document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "You Clicked Button4";

};

//2. register the onclick handlers after the DOM is complete
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    //select the buttons
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

    //register the same handler for each button
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", main);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Buttons Demo </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>String Machine</h2>
<p>
Enter a String: 
</p>
<input id= "inpt"> </input>
<button id="btn1">Reverse</button>
<button id="btn2">Vowel or no Vowel</button>
<button id="btn3">Count Vowels</button>
<button id="btn4">Digit or no Digit</button>
<br>
<hr style="width:23%; margin-left:0;">
<div id="outDiv"></div>
<script src="stringMach.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```